# Where does imagejpeg() function store images displayed on the fly?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

If I use the function `imagecreatefromjpeg` to create an image and then `imagejpeg` to display it to the browser on the fly and not save it to a file, I assume it gets temporarily stored in a location to be displayed. What is the path of the location?

Answer (score 1):

Although the documentation doesn't state, it appears to store it in memory.

Test script:

```
<?php

echo memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg');
echo memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
unset($im);
echo memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
238064
240360
240104
```

Answer (score 0):

I also believe it's stored in the local memory. You should be able to catch the image data like this and then hash it to base64 in order to display it in an image tag:

```
//...
ob_start(); 
imagejpeg( $img, NULL, 100 ); 
imagedestroy( $img ); 
$imageData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $imageData ).'">';
```